# How to access DocumentsProvider in my app directly without using intent?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, storage-access-framework

I want to create a DocumentsProvider to manage specified folder. I have another app needs to use this DocumentsProvider to browse/manage the files in the folder.

I saw many sample code which uses intent and startActivity, then using DocumentsUI to get URI. Is it possible to access DocumentsProvider directly by my app and without using intent?

I tried to use fixed URI for my DocumentsProvider, and tried to use DocumentsContract to access it, but it will encounter "SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID and Uri". I also used grantUriPermission() first, but it doesn't help.

Is any way to access DocumentsProvider with fixed (pre-defined) URI instead of the URI from returned intent?

Comment: `saw many sample code which invoke DocumentsUI`. Wonder what you mean with that. Can you give an example?

Comment: The point of `DocumentsProvider` is for those documents to be accessible to other apps via the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`). If that is not what you want, do not implement a `DocumentsProvider`. If you want the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` support and *also* want to directly work with the `DocumentsProvider`, you could try using `DocumentsContract`, but I do not know how your client app will get permission to work with the documents.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but get permission issue as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Like CommonsWare said in the comment, you probably are trying to use a thing that's for another purpose, but it's not impossible to achieve what you said.

It seems you own both apps, so you can let them share the same UID by assigning [sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) and you should be able to talk to the DocumentsProvider.

Alternatively you can define a special activity in the app that owns the DocumentsProvider where it grants URI permission to the other app. Then you should be able to access it. Though not sure if this is what you want because you still need to launch an intent to launch a non-UI activity.